# Substitute temporal gaps in result set with default value in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using this query to average a value (performance) over 3-minute intervals of an hour:

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('hour', created) AS created,
  (extract(minute FROM created)::int / 3) minute_part,
  worker,
  AVG(performance)
FROM perf_stats
WHERE
  group_id = 'foo' AND 
  worker = 'bar' AND
  created > '1.1.2021 19:00:00' AND
  created < '1.1.2021 20:00:00'
GROUP BY 1, 2, worker
ORDER BY 1, 2, worker;
```

This returns the following result set for the sample data set:

| created | minute_part | worker | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 10 | bar | 3 |

Now I'd like to fill in zeros for the performance when there are no rows satisfying the query. Resulting in this result set:

| created | minute_part | worker | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 0 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 1 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 2 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 3 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 4 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 5 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 6 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 7 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 8 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 9 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 10 | bar | 3 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 11 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 12 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 13 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 14 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 15 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 16 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 17 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 18 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 19 | bar | 0 |

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE perf_stats
(
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    group_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    worker TEXT NOT NULL,
    performance DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX IDX_PERFSTATS_CREATED on perf_stats(group_id, created);
```

**Sample Data:**

```
INSERT INTO perf_stats (group_id, worker, performance, created) 
VALUES('foo', 'bar', 2, '1.1.2021 19:30:00');

INSERT INTO perf_stats (group_id, worker, performance, created) 
VALUES('foo', 'bar', 4, '1.1.2021 19:31:00');
```

I've experimented with `generate_series` but did not get it working so far.

Comment: why just up to minute 19? any specific reason?

Comment: @eshirvana There are only 20 3-minute slices per hour. After that it wraps around and starts with zero again at the next hour.

Comment: I see, how about the avg , I see avg is not per hour , how do you calculate avg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to generate rows for all the minutes.  You can use `generate_series()` for this and then a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', gs.ts) AS created,
       (extract(minute FROM gs.ts)::int / 3) minute_part,
       worker,
       AVG(performance)
FROM generate_series('2021-01-01 19:00:00'::timestamp, '2021-01-01 20:00:00'::timestamp, interval '3 minute') gs(ts) LEFT JOIN
     perf_stats ps
     ON ps.group_id = 'foo' AND 
        ps.worker = 'bar' AND
        ps.created >= gs.ts AND
        ps.created < gs.ts + interval '3 minute'
GROUP BY 1, 2, worker
ORDER BY 1, 2, worker;
```